# Difference between 2 quadrature formulas $I_{2n}(f(x))$ and $I(f(x))$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, approximate-integration

Let $h = \frac{1}{n}$, $x_i = -1 + ih$ , $ i = 0, 1, ... , 2n,$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $p_{2n} (x)$ be a polynomial of degree at most $2n$ interpolating the function $f(x)$ at $x_i$ $(i = 0, 1, ..., 2n)$.

Let

$$ I(f(x)) = \int^{1}_{-1} f(x) dx,  $$ $$ I_{2n} (f(x)) = \int^{1}_{-1} p_{2n} (x) dx. $$

Then compute

$$ I_{2n}(\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}(ix^i)) - I (\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1}(ix^i)).$$

I thought of using Gaussian quadrature methods to solve this question but I am clueless as to how I can proceed. Also, is the answer indeed zero? Some hints and/or clarifications will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $p_{2n}=f$ if $f$ is any polynomial of degree at most $2n$.

You only have to care what happens to $f(x)=x^{2n+1}$, but as this is an odd function...

Comment: Hmm I understand that for odd functions, $\int^{1}_{-1} f(x) dx$ will be equal to zero and if $f$ is even then $\int^{1}_{-1} f(x) dx$ will be equal to $2\int^{1}_{0} f(x) dx$. Am I right to say that essentially I will have $0 - 0$?

Comment: No, the even terms give integrals different from zero. But because of the identity under interpolation, the integrand is the same on both sides.

Comment: Ah now that makes sense thanks! In any case, am I right to infer that since $I_{2n}$ deals with polynomials of degree up to $2n$, I will have to factor out the $x^{2n+1}$ term from $I_{2n}(f(x))$ and factorize with the corresponding  $x^{2n+1}$ term from $I$ such that i will get: 
$[I_{2n}(\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(ix^i)) - I (\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(ix^i))](2n+1)x^{2n+1}$ where the integral of $[I_{2n}(\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(ix^i)) - I (\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(ix^i))] = 0$ by uniqueness of the interpolating polynomials as you have suggested?

Comment: I think you mean the right thing. You could also separate out each term and make the statement more general for any polynomial of degree $2n+1$ or less.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the clarification! :)